# Vue - Cannot bind HTML Geo-location to component variable

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, geolocation

I'm having this weird issue where when I get the result of a HTML geolocation call, I cant bind it to Vue data, but I can console.log it successfully.

Vue method:

```
initGeolocation: function() {
            if( navigator.geolocation )
            {
               // Call getCurrentPosition with success and failure callbacks
               navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( success, fail );
            }
            else
            {
               return;
            }

            function success(position)
           {
               console.log(position.coords.latitude); //works
               this.lat = position.coords.latitude; //does not work
           }

           function fail()
           {
              console.log('fail')
           }
        },

  mounted() {
     this.lat = this.initGeolocation(); // does not work
     console.log(this.initGeolocation()) // returns undefined
    },
```

Data:

```
        lat: '',
        long: '',
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding the success and fail callbacks directly into the function? Its possible the `this` keyword is no longer referencing the vue instance and hence `this.lat` is not accessing the data variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word `this` refers to the scope of the function. When you nest another function inside, the word `this` now refers to the new/ smaller scope so `this.lat` is no longer defined. So we capture the out `this` in `vm` and use it inside functions.

```
methods: {

  initGeolocation: function() {
    var vm = this;
    if( navigator.geolocation)
    {
        // Call getCurrentPosition with success and failure callbacks
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( success, fail );
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

    function success(position)
    {
        vm.lat = position.coords.latitude; //should work now!!
    }

    function fail()
    {
      console.log('fail')
    }
  }
},
mounted() {
   this.initGeolocation();
},
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `mounted` you assign `this.lat` with the return of your `initGeolocation()` method. However this method does not return any data if it succeeds. Instead you write your result into `this.lat` which then will be overridden again by the void result of your method. So make sure your method `initGeolocation` either returns your geolocation data or you change your mounted method to call the method without assigning the return value to `this.lat`.

Also it seems like you just added the `initGeolocation` method to your component. Look into the `methods` property of vue components where this would belong.

So try this instead:

```
mounted() {
  this.initGeolocation(); 
  console.log(this.initGeolocation());
},

methods: {
  initGeolocation: function() {
    if( navigator.geolocation)
    {
        // Call getCurrentPosition with success and failure callbacks
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( success, fail );
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

    function success(position)
    {
        this.lat = position.coords.latitude; //does not work
    }

    function fail()
    {
      console.log('fail')
    }
  }
}
```